# Animating pie chart with Google Visualization

Tags: jquery, animation, charts, visualization

I am experimenting with google charts. I want a pie chart to animate from 0% to 75% (see the image below). I am attempting to achieve this through google charts. I am creating two sets of data, one will start at 99%, the other at 1%. I want to invert and animate these. I have achieved changing the values through animation, but cannot figure out how to get them to animate.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'text');
        data.addColumn('number', 'number');

        data.addRows(2);
        data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1);
        data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 99);

        var options = {
                        width:500,
                        height:500,
                        animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out',}
                      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        function aniChart(d,o){
          for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
            data.setValue(0, 1, i);
          }

          for (var i=99; i>00; i--) {
            data.setValue(1, 1, i);
          }
          setTimeout(function(){
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }, 1000);

        };

        aniChart();

      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: chart]

Comment: you want it to go blue/red/blue/red...and so on as the first iteration?

Comment: Ideally it would be white first, then the color would animate like a clock hand to the desired percent.

Comment: `aniChart` function is wrong. You are looping through all the values and then making a final single delayed draw call. There is no animation loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that function is not supported by Google Charts api - refer to [Supported Modifications](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#Supported_Modifications)

I think it may be easier if you use a different chart tool such as this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410

Comment: chart example is excellent. It relies on d3 library which is also excellent. It requires a browser that supports SVG. Perfect for mobile applications. You can animate, add touch events, alter the pie wedges interactively with some JS.

Answer (score 4):

Solving the original problem with the neat @Muhammad animation loop.

Initial values:

- Work: 0%
- Eat: 100%

The loop increases the value 1 unit and draw the pie every 30 milliseconds.

The loop stops when Work=75% is reached.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'text');
data.addColumn('number', 'number');

data.addRows(2);
data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
data.setValue(0, 1, 0.0);
data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
data.setValue(1, 1, 100.0);

var options = {
    width:500,
    height:500
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);

// initial value
var percent = 0;
// start the animation loop
var handler = setInterval(function(){
    // values increment
    percent += 1;
    // apply new values
    data.setValue(0, 1, percent);
    data.setValue(1, 1, 100 - percent);
    // update the pie
    chart.draw(data, options);
    // check if we have reached the desired value
    if (percent > 74)
        // stop the loop
        clearInterval(handler);
}, 30);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>         
</head>
<body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

    <script>
              google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',          
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var counter = 0;

    var handler = setInterval(function(){ 
        counter = counter + 0.1
        options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',           
          slices: { 1: {offset: counter},                       
                    3: {offset: counter},                       
                    5: {offset: counter},
          }
        };
        chart.draw(data, options);

        if (counter > 0.3) clearInterval(handler);
    }, 200);        
  } 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: put this element in body tag <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div> and <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>          in head tag

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.